# Last Order Date and YTD sales in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

**CUSTOMERS**

```
CUSTNUM
STATUS (1 inactive, 2 active)
CUSTNAME
```

**INVOICES**

```
INVNUM
INVDATE
INVTOTAL
CUSTNUM
```

I am looking to get YTD total sales for the active customers, whose number ends in 00 and their last invoice date (could be any time in the past, not just the last year). Basically, if the last purchase was before 2018, there would be nothing in the total column. I can't get the totals to work and it doesn't display customers who haven't purchased anything this year. Thank you for your help!

```
SELECT 
    BP.CUSTNUM, BP.STATUS, BP.CUSTNAME, 
    MAX(SI.INVDATE), SUM(SI2.INVTOTAL)
FROM 
    dbo.CUSTOMERS AS BP
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.INVOICES AS SI ON BP.CUSTNUM = SI.CUSTNUM
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.INVOICES AS SI2 ON BP.CUSTNUM = SI2.CUSTNUM
WHERE 
    BP.STATUS= 2 
    AND BP.CUSTNUM LIKE '%00'
    AND SI2.INVDATE BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '10/18/2018'
GROUP BY 
    BP.CUSTNUM, BP.STATUS, BP.CUSTNAME 
ORDER BY 
    BP.CUSTNUM
```

Comment: This is because your where clause checking for the date has turned your left join into an inner join. Move that predicate to the join instead. Also be careful with BETWEEN, especially with dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Sean commented, the `where` clause on `InvDate` will convert the join into into `inner join` that's why it doesn't display customers who haven't purchased anything this year. Also you don't have to join same table twice to get `Max` InDate and conditional `SUM`. You can use `CASE` expression to calculate total based on condition on `InvDate`, something like below.

```
SELECT 
    BP.CUSTNUM, 
    BP.STATUS, 
    BP.CUSTNAME, 
    MAX(SI.INVDATE), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(SM.INVDATE) = 2018 THEN SI.INVTOTAL ELSE 0 END) AS YTD_INVTOTAL
FROM 
    dbo.CUSTOMERS AS BP
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.INVOICES AS SI ON BP.CUSTNUM = SI.CUSTNUM
WHERE 
    BP.STATUS= 2 
    AND BP.CUSTNUM LIKE '%00'
GROUP BY 
    BP.CUSTNUM, BP.STATUS, BP.CUSTNAME 
ORDER BY 
    BP.CUSTNUM
```

Comment: Thank you, guys! It looks so simple when I look at your code!